# Show Custom Tooltip with Bound Data on WPF Pie Chart?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using Microsoft WPF Toolkit to display a Pie Chart with favorite fruits and corresponding percentages.

```
    Fruit     |   Percentage
    Apple     |   89%
    Grapes    |   9%
    Orange    |   2%
```

I want to display Custom Tooltip with fruit name and percentage value every time I move my cursor on to a fruit on the pie chart. [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVd1j.png)

**My Code**

```
                <DVC:Chart Name="chartControl1">
                    <DVC:PieSeries IndependentValuePath="fruitsList"
                                   DependentValuePath="percentageList"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"
                                   DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
                    </DVC:PieSeries>
                </DVC:Chart>
```

**What I tried..**

```
ToolTip="{Binding fruitsList}"
```

This doesn't show up any tooltip on to the Pie Chart.

PS: I do not want to use any third-party chart controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ToolTip is a ContentControl. So you need to set the tooltip in a way like this:

```
<DVC:Chart Name="chartControl1">
    <DVC:PieSeries IndependentValuePath="fruitsList"
                   DependentValuePath="percentageList"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"
                   DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
    </DVC:PieSeries>
    <DVC:Chart.ToolTip>
       <ToolTip Content="{Binding fruitsList}" />
    </DVC:Chart.ToolTip>
</DVC:Chart>
```

Provided, that your fruitsList can be shown as content and is a property. You can show your fruitsList in anyway you want inside the tooltip. For instance with a Grid:

```
<DVC:Chart.ToolTip>
  <Grid>
     ...
  </Grid>
</DVC:Chart.ToolTip>
```

And then format your content as you want

Comment: This is not working in my case